# Publishing an .apk into IBM Application Center from Application Center command-line tools

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-appcenter

I'm trying to publish an .apk into my Application Center through console. I've followed this note but it doesn't work in my environment:

https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/7.1/moving-production/distributing-mobile-applications-with-application-center/#cmdLineTools

If I type :

> ./acdeploytool.sh /home/miguel/Downloads/HelloWorldMyHelloAndroid.apk

I get this error message:

> FWLAC0803E: Unable to connect:
>           Connection refused
>           Perhaps the server or context is wrongly specified.
>           File:/home/myUser/Downloads/HelloWorldMyHelloAndroid.apk

And if I try another way using this java command:

> java com.ibm.appcenter.Upload -f http://localhost:9080 -c applicationcenter -u demo -p demo /home/myUser/Downloads/HelloWorldMyHelloAndroid.apk

I get this one:

> Error: Could not find or load main class com.ibm.appcenter.Upload

I don't get any errors when I do this 'publish' operation directly in Application Center or through MobileFirst Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Miguel, whether you use the script or the Java command, you need to specify the arguments to use.  Please try the following:

./acdeploytool.sh -s http://localhost:9080 -c applicationcenter -u demo -p demo /home/miguel/Downloads/HelloWorldMyHelloAndroid.apk

I tried a similar command in my environment and was able to successfully deploy the apk to Application Center.  If the command still does not work, make sure that the host/port that you are using are correct, and that the username and password are valid.

For the Java command that you executed, I see a few problems.  First, the -cp argument needs to be specified in order to add the applicationcenterdeploytool.jar and json4j.jar files to the classpath.  Next, the command shows "-f", but it should be "-s" to specify the server.  Lastly, the path that was specified for the .apk is different than what you specified in the first command:  myUser vs. miguel.  So make sure that the correct path is used.  If there are any further questions, let me know.  Thanks.